# Debugging font substitution in windows UNIDRV

Tags: windows, fonts, driver, printers, glyph-substitution

I am working on a UNIDRV-based printer driver, and am having an issue with font substitution.  UNIDRV is not using any of the device fonts.  All fonts are being downloaded to the printer one glyph at a time.  Are there any logs for UNIDRV, and/or is there any way to debug UNIDRV, particularly the font substitution?

The development and target machines are all Windows 7 (32-bit).

Comment: There's no debug logging from within UNIDRV that I know of, but I doubt it would tell you much anyway.  The problem most likely lies in your GPD file.

Comment: Yeah, the GPD file may be the problem, as could the font files, but without any sort of diagnostics it is impossible to tell the error.  Of further note, the WinDDK samples also ignore the device fonts, as do the production HP drivers.  We are at a loss as to how to proceed.

Comment: I've worked with print drivers quite a bit but I've never had to support device fonts so I'm a bit vague on this area.  Does your driver implement the font DDI calls?  (OEMQueryFont, OEMQueryFontTree, etc)  It's my understanding that you have to implement all those entry points to support device fonts.

Comment: No, I am not implementing these.  From what I read under http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx they should not be required.  Thanks for the lead, I will look and see where that takes us...